# `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError) Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to iterate over a JSON parsed hash table (that has nested Array's of hashes) and insert into a Text Table .  The JSON parsed code that I am trying to iterate over is:

```
{"server"=>{"security_groups"=>[{"name"=>"default"}], "adminPass"=>"LhXEPMkYmqF7",   "id"=>"82b7e32b-f62b-4106-b499-e0046250229f", "links"=>[{"href"=>"http://10.30.1.49:8774/v2/89fc0b9d984d49fba5328766e923958f/servers/82b7e32b-f62b-4106-b499-e0046250229f", "rel"=>"self"}, {"href"=>"http://10.30.1.49:8774/89fc0b9d984d49fba5328766e923958f/servers/82b7e32b-f62b-4106-b499-e0046250229f", "rel"=>"bookmark"}], "OS-DCF:diskConfig"=>"MANUAL"}}
```

The code I am using to iterate over the top is:

```
server_table = Text::Table.new do | t |
      t.head = ['Server ID', 'Server URL', 'Admin Password']
   end
response = JSON.parse(r)

response['server'].each do | serv_info |
  server_table.rows << [["#{serv_info['id']}", "#{serv_info['links'][0]['href']}", "#{serv_info['adminPass']}"]]
end

puts server_table
```

I am getting the error:

```
/lib/get_token.rb:166:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from ./lib/get_token.rb:166:in `create_server'
    from ./lib/get_token.rb:165:in `each'
    from ./lib/get_token.rb:165:in `create_server'
```

If I individually use puts to print out each command they work fine, but the iteration does not.  The commands that pull the correct info are:

```
puts response['server']['links'][0]['href']
puts response['server']['id']
puts response['server']['adminPass']
```

All 3 of those work, but if I try and iterate over them I get the string error.  I know it has something to do with .each returning an Array of hashes but I do not fully understand why the PUTS command is working without issue in the script and also in IRB.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of using `puts`, try using `pp`, which will output a formatted version of the data. It's a temporary way to help visualize what your data structure *really* is. `puts` can gloss over the nesting by adding an extra line-feed that you don't really pay attention to.

Comment: Thats good to know, especially since I am new to this :)  Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `serv_info` is a pair of a map represented as an array of 2 elements. Therefore everything after `<<` in your code is just wrong.

The secret to avoid such mistakes is to stop trying to obfuscate your own code.

`server_table.rows` should contain all possible triples of server ID, link and a password.

```
response = # { "server" => ...}
server = response['server']
server_id = server['id']
link_infos = server['links']
admin_pass = server['adminPass']

link_infos.each do |link_info|
  link = link_info['href']
  server_table.rows << [server_id, link, admin_pass]
end
```

*Update*

We can easily use this code to process multiple servers

```
response = # [ {"server" => ...}, ...]
response.each do |server|
   ... # above code snippet goes here 
       # or you may extract it into a method and call it here
end
```

Also I want to mention that `irb` is really great for dealing with this kind of problems. It is a command line Ruby interpreter and it's great for prototyping. It prints out result of each statement you type and has an autocompletion to help you find required classes/methods. Instead of waiting several hours to get an SO answer to simple question you will get it using `irb` in a couple of minutes.

Comment: hoha, thank you.  I am new to ruby, only two weeks in so I really appreciate the answer.  I was trying to compact the code I guess, but I see where that would get me into serious trouble in the future.  You rock!

Comment: Next coding question and I want to see if I get this right.  If I get a JSON response that I parse out that has multiple ['server'] entries (creation of multiple server) would I iterate over your code using http://pastebin.com/MP0RJy2K

Comment: @hoha - think I forgot to add this for a notification

Comment: There is a mistake in you snippet, in `json_response['server'].each` you have an array `json_resonse` and arrays can not be accessed with a string keys (like "server") - you will get an error. See the updated post.

Comment: @hoha - so I went through the code this morning and was not able to get it to work, however you did lead me to think about the arrays.  It turns out that when I run a response.each | res | it converts response into a 2 position array.  response[0] being "server" and response[1] being the hash table.  I was able to fix it by doing this: http://pastebin.com/WBBQCU58    This is tested and working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean just

```
serv_info = response['server']
server_table.rows << [["#{serv_info['id']}", "#{serv_info['links'][0]['href']}",      "#{serv_info['adminPass']}"]]
```

Since `response['server']` is a hash not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
server_table.rows << [["#{serv_info['id']}", "#{serv_info['links'][0]['href']}", "#{serv_info['adminPass']}"]]
```

Try:

```
server_table.rows += [["#{serv_info['id']}", "#{serv_info['links'][0]['href']}", "#{serv_info['adminPass']}"]]
```

Or:

```
server_table.rows << ["#{serv_info['id']}", "#{serv_info['links'][0]['href']}", "#{serv_info['adminPass']}"]
```